# export BigQuery output to Google CloudStore

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-bigtable

Our organization has  data in Google Bigtable - hosted  by our Vendor. We want to run jobs in BigQuery to query  from Bigtable and export the data to CloudStore as .csv files without the  storing the data as a dataset in BigQuery.

We do not want to store in BigQuery datasets as we are not doing any analysis using BigQuery as all Analysis is done using on premise Analytical solution.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options, and the best solution would be to automate using Cloud Workflows.

The steps I see would be:

1. Export from BigTable in Avro or Parquet format to Cloud Storage.
   There is a `gcloud` and API way to do this described [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-batch#gcloud_3).
2. You then import the exported files into BigQuery.
   There is a a way to use `bq` CLI tool and API way as well to do this described [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-avro#bq).
3. Then you export from BigQuery to multiple CSV files as it's documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#exportingmultiple).

You get multiple CSV files, you can then run the `gcloud compose` tool to merge them.

All the above can be done in Cloud Workflows. Each call can be implemented either via API (preferred) or using the command line options using Cloud Build triggers for example. For Workflow syntax you can [get guidance](https://medium.com/google-cloud/automate-the-execution-of-bigquery-queries-with-cloud-workflows-9fffe0557dbb) from this article, and the linked content from the footer section of the article.